# json response is not returned using spring 3.1

Tags: java, xml, json, spring

I am trying to return json and xml response using ResponseBody, and it does work fine for xml but doesnt return json. My request uri for xml is '../home.xml' and for json is '../home.json' from controller method:

```
@RequestMapping("home.*")
public  @ResponseBody Message homeOther(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap mv){
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.setDetail("I am here at home");
    msg.setUploadDate(new Date());

    mv.addAttribute("message", msg);

    return msg;
}
```

And here is the dispatcher servlet:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ym"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/>
</bean>


<bean id="velocityConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/views"/>
</bean>

<!-- Simple ViewResolver for Velocity, appending ".vm" to logical view names -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="2" />
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".vm"/>
    <property name="toolboxConfigLocation" value="/WEB-INF/toolbox.xml"/>
    <!-- if you want to use the Spring Velocity macros, set this property to true -->
    <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
    <property name="contentType" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="xstreamMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller" />


<bean id="xmlView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView"
      >
      <constructor-arg ref="xstreamMarshaller" />
</bean>

<bean id="jsonView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonHttpMessageConverter" />
            <ref bean="marshallingHttpMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
</bean>

<bean id="marshallingHttpMessageConverter"
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="xstreamMarshaller"/>
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="xstreamMarshaller"/>
</bean>



<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
  <property name="order" value="1" />
  <property name="mediaTypes">
    <map>
       <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
       <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
    </map>
  </property>

  <property name="defaultViews">
    <list>
      <!-- JSON View -->
      <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
      </bean>

      <ref bean="xmlView" />
     </list>
  </property>
  <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />

</bean>
```

Here is XML response:

```
<com.ym.mongodb.model.Message>
 <messageId>0</messageId>
 <detail>I am here at home</detail>
 <uploadDate>2013-03-09 09:56:46.606 UTC</uploadDate>
</com.ym.mongodb.model.Message>
```

My problems are:
1. what is worng with the configuration? why it doesnt return a json response.?
2. Why the xml it returns, display fullyqualified name of Message?
 i am using Spring 3.1.

**Edit**:
Interestingly, it does create json n xml correctly when request type is set properly. But still the 2nd problem does exists.

Comment: what are the request headers used?

Comment: You need to send the request header `Accept=application/json`

Comment: request header is they default, i havent changed its header. Also, i would like to just call the url without changing anything in header. Is it possible? thanks for the quick replies.

Comment: no, because the return type is decided via the `Accept` header, can you do one thing, inspect the ajax request using your browser developer tool/firebug then look under the section request headers and see what is the value for `Accept`

Comment: its application/xhtml+xml

Comment: that is why xml response is sent back, how is the ajax request created? is jQuery or any other library used

Comment: it isnt an ajax request, i have just called it directly from browser. Also, as per spring, [ContentNegotiatingViewResolve](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.html#setFavorPathExtension(boolean)) supports some parameters like favorpathextension, which looks into path for extension. Is it possiblye through this way?

Comment: what is the url extension used, try using `json` and set `favorPathExtension` to true

Comment: same result, with favorPathExtension using json as extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you try to achieve in detail so I don't know if I can help but I'll give it a shot.

First of all you can try and add accept headers. Below is an example.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home/yourpath", method = RequestMethod.GET,
headers = "Accept=application/xml, application/json")
```

By adding the accept header json and xml requests will be accepted when invoking your method and parsing data as for example with a curl client. Also maybe you should consider to set a request method explicitly.

When you send the request to the client make sure that you have "Content-Type: application/json" or "Content-Type: application/xml" added to the header of your request depending on the content you send. Otherwise you'll get an unsupported content type error because you maybe send the wrong content type.

There are two ways of actually displaying the correct content type in Spring.

1: Through parsing/accepting the right content-type in the header of your request (by condiguring accept headers in the client).

2: Through configuring file extensions (there are certain default file extensions that should work out of the box. xml and json are covered.). Try to add .xml or .json to the end of your uri.

Have a look here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-multiple-representations

Look at following example: 
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-contentnegotiatingviewresolver-example/

I can't help you with your second problem.

I hope this helps. Good luck.

Kind regards,
Chris

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, i need to add Content Type for sure to fix the first problem, without changing much in rest of the code i have shown. I was trying to fix it without defining Content-Type. But looks like thats necessary to be defined. Also by this it does fix the 2nd problem as well.